# how to use client chat on different pc

Tags: java, android, chat

I have the following code which works perfect when executed from the same eclipse IDE same system(PC).
But I tried running the code below in 2 separate systems and it does not work.I don't know what the port and ip change in the code should be.
Please let me know what I need to change to make this java application work?

Thanks in Advance.

**SERVER**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Server extends JFrame{

   private JTextField userText;
   private JTextArea chatWindow;
   private ObjectOutputStream output;
   private ObjectInputStream input;
   private ServerSocket server;
   private Socket connection;

   //constructor
   public Server(){
      super(" Instant Messenger");
      userText = new JTextField();
      userText.setEditable(false);
      userText.addActionListener(
         new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
               sendMessage(event.getActionCommand());
               userText.setText("");
            }
         }
      );
      add(userText, BorderLayout.NORTH);
      chatWindow = new JTextArea();
      add(new JScrollPane(chatWindow));  //chat window needs to be scrollable so that when new messages are added it can scroll as needed
      setSize(300,150);
      setVisible(true);
   }

   //set up and run the server
   public void startRunning(){
      try{
         server = new ServerSocket(6789, 100);
         while(true){
            try{
               waitForConnection();
               setupStreams();
               whileChatting();
            }catch(EOFException eofException){
               showMessage("\n Server ended the connection! ");
            }finally{
               closeCrap();
            }
         }
      }catch(IOException ioException){
         ioException.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

   //wait for connection, then display connection information
   private void waitForConnection() throws IOException{
      showMessage(" Waiting for someone to connect... \n");
      connection = server.accept();
      showMessage(" Now connected to " + connection.getInetAddress().getHostName());
   }

   //get stream to send and receive data
   private void setupStreams() throws IOException{
      output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
      output.flush();
      input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
      showMessage("\n Streams are now setup! \n");
   }

   //during the chat conversation
   private void whileChatting() throws IOException{
      String message = " You are now connected! ";
      sendMessage(message);
      ableToType(true);
      do{
         try{
            message = (String) input.readObject();
            showMessage("\n" + message);
         }catch(ClassNotFoundException classNotFoundException){
            showMessage("\n idk wtf that user sent!");
         }
      }while(!message.equals("CLIENT - END"));
   }

   //close streams and sockets after you are done chatting
   private void closeCrap(){
      showMessage("\n Closing connections... \n");
      ableToType(false);
      try{
         output.close();
         input.close();
         connection.close();
      }catch(IOException ioException){
         ioException.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

   //send a message to client
   private void sendMessage(String message){
      try{
         output.writeObject("SERVER - " + message);
         output.flush();
         showMessage("\nSERVER - " + message);
      }catch(IOException ioException){
         chatWindow.append("\n ERROR: DUDE I CANT SEND THAT MESSAGE");
      }
   }

   //updates chatWindow
   private void showMessage(final String text){
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
         new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
               chatWindow.append(text);
            }
         }
      );
   }

   //let the user type stuff into their box
   private void ableToType(final boolean tof){
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
         new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
               userText.setEditable(tof);
            }
         }
      );
   }

}
```

**ServerTest**

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class ServerTest {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Server sally = new Server();
      sally.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      sally.startRunning();
   }
}
```

**Client**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Client extends JFrame{

   private JTextField userText;
   private JTextArea chatWindow;
   private ObjectOutputStream output;
   private ObjectInputStream input;
   private String message = "";
   private String serverIP;
   private Socket connection;

   //constructor
   public Client(String host){
      super("Client Messenger!");
      serverIP = host;
      userText = new JTextField();
      userText.setEditable(false);
      userText.addActionListener(
         new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
               sendMessage(event.getActionCommand());
               userText.setText("");
            }
         }
      );
      add(userText, BorderLayout.NORTH);
      chatWindow = new JTextArea();
      add(new JScrollPane(chatWindow), BorderLayout.CENTER);
      setSize(300,150);
      setVisible(true);
   }

   //connect to server
   public void startRunning(){
      try{
         connectToServer();
         setupStreams();
         whileChatting();
      }catch(EOFException eofException){
         showMessage("\n Client terminated connection");
      }catch(IOException ioException){
         ioException.printStackTrace();
      }finally{
         closeCrap();
      }
   }

   //connect to server
   private void connectToServer() throws IOException{
      showMessage("Attempting connection... \n");
      connection = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(serverIP), 6789);
      showMessage("Connected to: " + connection.getInetAddress().getHostName() );
   }

   //set up streams to send and receive messages
   private void setupStreams() throws IOException{
      output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
      output.flush();
      input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
      showMessage("\n Dude your streams are now good to go! \n");
   }

   //while chatting with server
   private void whileChatting() throws IOException{
      ableToType(true);
      do{
         try{
            message = (String) input.readObject();
            showMessage("\n" + message);
         }catch(ClassNotFoundException classNotfoundException){
            showMessage("\n I dont know that object type");
         }
      }while(!message.equals("SERVER - END"));
   }

   //close the streams and sockets
   private void closeCrap(){
      showMessage("\n closing crap down...");
      ableToType(false);
      try{
         output.close();
         input.close();
         connection.close();
      }catch(IOException ioException){
         ioException.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

   //send messages to server
   private void sendMessage(String message){
      try{
         output.writeObject("CLIENT - " + message);
         output.flush();
         showMessage("\nCLIENT - " + message);
      }catch(IOException ioException){
         chatWindow.append("\n something messed up sending message hoss!");
      }
   }

   //change/update chatWindow
   private void showMessage(final String m){
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
         new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
               chatWindow.append(m);
            }
         }
      );
   }

   //gives user permission to type crap into the text box
   private void ableToType(final boolean tof){
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
         new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
               userText.setEditable(tof);
            }
         }
      );     
   }
}
```

**ClientTest**

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class ClientTest {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Client charlie;
      charlie = new Client("127.0.0.1");
      charlie.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      charlie.startRunning();
   }
}
```

Comment: What does this have to do with Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are launching your client by running the `ClientTest` class then you need to update it to use the server IP. In your current ClientTest code you are connecting to the server using the localhost IP:

```
  charlie = new Client("127.0.0.1");
```

Update it to use the server IP:

```
  charlie = new Client("use server IP");
```

server IP is the IP address of the machine where you are running your `Server` class.

Comment: Thank You Sir for your input .IT worked from another PC .What need to change if I host it on my domain : www.xyz.com  then .What will be the ip I need to enter into client?

Comment: Also what difference would be made if its client to client chat ?  And If I try the same onto Android device then what would the ip be??Please answer the queries it would be of a great help.

Comment: The simplest network topology to make two clients talking to each other is that they need to be in same domain or private network. Client-client chat will work when client is combination of client and server i.e. both the clients can make and listen for connnections.

Answer (score 0):

The IP and port should correspond to the other side. Assuming ports are forwarded, the port should be the same of the other side's listening port. The IP should be that of the other endpoint.

ServerTest should be OK, while ClientTest will need the IP to be changed to that of where the server is running(assuming ports are open and forwarded, not blocked by a NAT or firewall), but the port should stay the same.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using different ports, maybe even let yourself choose your port instead of hardcoding it into your code. Sometimes it won't work because the port is already in use.

Server:

```
public void startRunning(serverPort){
 try{
 server = new ServerSocket(serverPort, 100);
}
```

Client:

```
private void connectToServer(portNumber) throws IOException{
  showMessage("Attempting connection... \n");
  connection = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(serverIP), portNumber);
  showMessage("Connected to: " + connection.getInetAddress().getHostName() );
}
```

Probably needs some more changes to it, but that's how I would do it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide IP address of the system in which the server is running to the client object.
It is better approach to ask user the server IP and PORT before connection.